# UDisks script to list all mounted USB devices

Tags: c, linux, perl, lvm

i wanted an UDisks script to list all the usb devices that are mounted on my system , which 
must have ability to detect LVM devices.

Perl / C / Shell any is fine

Many thanks.

P.S: Hal is deprecated on my Gentoo and removed

Comment: Go ahead and write it. Come back when you have any specific problems or questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loads of info about udisks here http://igurublog.wordpress.com/2011/01/26/a-custom-udisks-automounter/